# issue with upstart job for statsd

Tags: node.js, upstart, statsd

I am using the following statsd.conf file in my /etc/init directory (and sudo start statsd) to launch statsd.  When I run sudo start statsd, I receive the error posted  below the conf file.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot/resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

**/etc/init/statsd.conf**

```
#!upstart
description "Statsd node.js server"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
    export HOME="/root"

    echo $$ > /var/run/statsd.pid
    exec sudo -u www-data node /home/username/anotherDir/statsd/stats.js /home/userName/anotherDir/statsd/localConfig.js  >> /var/log/statsd.log 2> /var/log/statsd.error.log
end script

pre-start script
    # Date format same as (new Date()).toISOString() for consistency
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/statsd.log
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/statsd.pid
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/statsd.log
end script
```

**Error Message:**

```
fs.js:1051
    throw errnoException(process._errno, 'watch');
          ^
Error: watch ENOENT
    at errnoException (fs.js:1019:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1051:11)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1076:11)
    at new Configurator (/home/username/anotherDir/statsd/lib/config.js:26:6)
    at Object.exports.configFile (/home/username/anotherDir/statsd/lib/config.js:36:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/username/anotherDir/statsd/stats.js:146:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pilot error - the config file was named config.js and not localConfig.js.

Answer (score 3):

The error `ENOENT` is caused by a [file not found](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/uv/include/uv.h#L109). I would double-check your `stats.js` script

Comment: Yes, as per my note above, I mentioned the wrong config file name in the script.